# WPF Binding directly to the DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Is there a keyword to directly bind to the DataContext and not to an attribute of it?

I heard about the workaround with a Self Object. My problem is that I open a Window, and give an ObservableCollection as argument, which is set to the DataContext.

Here the WPF(xaml.cs) ctor

```
public Depot(ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<ItemManager.Item>> totalDepot)
{
    this.FullDepotList = totalDepot;
    this.DataContext = FullDepotList[1];
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

The XAML Code snippet where I would preferably bind to the DataContext directly or to "this":

```
<WrapPanel>
    <ListBox 
         ItemsSource="{Binding this, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"       
         ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ItemWithCoolTooltipTemplate}" 
         Focusable="False">
    </ListBox>
</WrapPanel>
```

Comment: The answer that @ASh gave you is a *far* superior answer than the one you currently have selected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To bind directly to the DataContext and not to an attribute of it, don't write any binding Path. Make it just `{Binding}`. `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is not needed because ItemsSource doesn't change from view.

```
<ListBox 
     ItemsSource="{Binding}"
     ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ItemWithCoolTooltipTemplate}" 
     Focusable="False">
</ListBox>
```

alternatively use `Path=.` to code "bind entire DataContext here" requirement

```
<ListBox 
     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}"
     ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ItemWithCoolTooltipTemplate}" 
     Focusable="False">
</ListBox>
```

any tricks with RelativeSource/ElementName are usually necessary to change binding source. In this case DataContext (binding source) is simply inherited from parent Window.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following trick. 
Add name property to your Window - `<Window ... Name="myWindow" ...>`
Use such a construction to bind to the property or whatever you need - `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=myWindow}" ... />`